# Why does the nil coalescing operator wrap an implicitly unwrapped default value?

Tags: swift

I see there is no reason that operator returns implicitly unwrapped optional. But what is the point that it wraps an implicitly unwrapped optional default value into optional (wrapped)? I just would expect non-optional result. Am I thinking somehow wrong here?

```
var defaultValue: Int! = 0
var optional: Int?

let result = optional ?? defaultValue

print(defaultValue.dynamicType) // ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>
print(result.dynamicType) // Optional<Int>
```

Comment: The interesting point here is that there are situations where an IUO is *not* implicitly unwrapped. Pattern matching is another example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in the Swift module where the nil coalescing operator is declared.  `??` explicitly returns an optional if the second operand is a non-optional (if you let Swift infer the type):

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T?) rethrows -> T?

@warn_unused_result
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T
```

```
let val1: Int? = nil
let val2 = 1
let val3 = val1 ?? val2 // 1

val3.dynamicType // Int.Type
```

Comment: Why would you use a nil coalescing operator with a non optional value?? val2 will never be used

Comment: Perhaps you meant: "if the second operand is a non-optional .." ?

Comment: @LeoDabus just for the sake of the example.  It's trivial.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is merely one of inferred type. Don't let Swift infer the type here. Write this:

```
let result : Int = optional ?? defaultValue
```

Now you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: It depends what you want an answer to. JAL explained the phenomena correctly. My approach was practical: I was assuming that you just wanted to get the expected answer and get on with life. :)

Comment: Or alternatively, `let result = optional ?? defaultValue as Int`